# Complex Analysis Questions - $|z + 2| + |z - 2| = \sqrt{10}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots, absolute-value

I'm just starting in a Complex Analysis course, and I am stuck on a couple questions. The questions are as follows:

> If $z = a + bi$ is a point on the curve $|z + 2| + |z - 2| = \sqrt{10},$
>   find the equation relating $a$ and $b$.

and

> Find the roots of $\bar z ^2 + z + 1 = 0.$

Please note that $\bar z$ is referring to the complex conjugate of $z.$

Thanks to anyone who tries to give me a hand! I tried for so long yesterday to solve these, and they're driving me nuts!

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: For the second part, if you write $z = a + bi$ and then expand your polynomial (noting that the conjugate of $z$ is $a - bi$), and group together real and imaginary parts, you will get two equations for the $a$ and $b$ that are both zero. The imaginary part of the equation should make it easy to express $a$ in terms of $b$, or vice versa. Then you can solve the equation for the real part.

Comment: It is an Euclidean geometry question, more than a complex analysis one. What is the locus of points such that the sum of the distances from two fixed points equals a constant?

Comment: I've exhausted myself trying to replace z with a + bi, then trying to solve for a or b in both examples.. I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $z=a+ib$ in $$|z+2|+|z-2| = \sqrt{10}\;,$$ We get $\sqrt{(a+2)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{(a-2)^2+b^2}=\sqrt{10}$

Now Let $$PA=\sqrt{(a+2)^2+b^2}$$ and $$PB = \sqrt{(a-2)^2+b^2}$$

So we get $PA+PB=\sqrt{10}........(1)$

$$\displaystyle (PA+PB)(PA-PB)=\sqrt{10}(PA-PB)\Rightarrow PA-PB = \frac{(PA)^2-(PB)^2}{\sqrt{10}} = \frac{8a}{\sqrt{10}}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle PA-PB = \frac{8a}{\sqrt{10}}.........(2)$$

Now Add $(1)$ and $(2)\;,$ We get

$$\displaystyle 2PA = \sqrt{10}+\frac{8a}{\sqrt{10}} = \frac{10+8a}{\sqrt{10}}\Rightarrow PA=\frac{5+4a}{\sqrt{10}}\Rightarrow (PA)^2= \frac{5+4a}{\sqrt{10}}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle (a+2)^2+b^2 = \frac{5+4a}{\sqrt{10}}\Rightarrow 10\left[(a+2)^2+b^2\right] = (5+4a)^2$$

$(2)$ Given $\bar{z}^2+z=1=0\;,$ Now taking Conjugate, we get $z^2+\bar{z}=1=0$

Now $z^2-\bar{z}^2-(z-\bar{z}) =0\Rightarrow (z-\bar{z})\cdot (z+\bar{z}-1)=0$

So we get $z=\bar{z}$ and $z+\bar{z} = 1$

So $z=\bar{z}$ means $z=a$ Purely Real. and $z+\bar{z}=1$ Means $\displaystyle a=\frac{1}{2}$

$\bullet\; $ If $z=\bar{z}\Rightarrow z=a$ Put into $\bar{z}^2+z=1=0$

we get $a^2+a+1=0$ solving that we get no real value of $a$

So no complex no. $z$ in that case.

$\bullet\; $ If $\displaystyle z+\bar{z} =1 \Rightarrow a=\frac{1}{2}\;,$ Now put $\displaystyle z=\frac{1}{2}+ib$ in $\bar{z}^2+z=1=0$ and solve for $b$

Comment: Hmm.. This only answers the first part. But I'm having some trouble understanding what you're trying to say. Why did you use 2A = 4? Also, how does e = 10^(1/2)/2A?

Comment: Sorry  user3495690 I was wrong in first part Now I  wiil dit my post for first part, Extremely sorry.

Comment: That's okay! Thanks for all your help! :)